# Is there a solution to convert HTML, CSS and JS files to a WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I created an HTML page that includes a CSS and JS file, the JS have some functions and an AJAX request to a local PHP page. I want to convert this work to a WordPress plugin so I can install it with a [shortcode] in my WordPress website. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You won't have a shortcode that would be generated by wordpess with your code.

For the plugin, I recommend you to follow that tutorial:

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-plugin-development-guide/

And for the shortcode you will need to create one, here is the Wordpress documentation:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Follow the guide, to create a plugin, and have that plugin register the shortcode for you as well.